# why does constructor work first time then return typeerror?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a constructor function that creates an object. The first time I call it, I get no errors and everything works fine. The second time I call it I get the following error:

Here is where the constructor is called:

```
$('#start_realtime_tracking').click( function() {

//first, clear out any previous layers
clearLayers();
clearInterval(updatePositions);

//initial the tracking variables to clear out any last usage
aircraftTracking = [];
callSigns = [];
devID_query = [];

console.log('controller-1049: start RealTime Tracking');

// First, get a list of the aircraft we will be tracking
var i =0;
$.each($("input[class='form-check-input callSign_checkbox-rt']:checked"), function () {
  var aircraft = new aircraftObj( $(this).prop('value'), $(this).prop('id'), new Date(), getPolycolor($(this).prop('value')) );
  aircraftTracking.push( aircraft );
  callSigns.push( $(this).prop('value') );
  imeis.push( $(this).prop('value') );
  //console.log('adding callsign ', $(this).prop('value'), ' i= ', i++);
});
```

imeis are defined in a global scope. Here is the constructor itself:

```
function aircraftObj (imei, callSign, timeStart, color) {
  console.log('aircraft Constructor: ', imei, ' , ', callSign, ' , ', 
                timeStart, ' , ', color );
  this.imei = imei;
  this.callSign = callSign;
  this.currentPosition = L.latLng[0,0];
  this.previousPosition = L.latLng[0,0];
  this.alt = 0;
  this.speed = 0;
  this.azimuth = 0;
  this.attribute - [];
  this.positions = [];
  this.startMarker = 0;
  this.endMarker = 0;
  this.flightMarker = 0;
  this.polyline = [0,0]; // list of all polylines.
  this.polyColor = color.replace('0x', '#');
  this.moving = 0;
  this.trackedFromStart = 0;
  this.markerColor;
  this.firstMovement = timeStart;
  this.lastMovement = timeStart;
  this.tmpmarker1 = 0;
  this.tmpmarker2 = 0;
};
```

I'm not logging any other errors, so I don't think memory is getting corrupted, but obviously, something is going on. How can I track this down?

Here is the error:

```
controller.js:1327 Uncaught TypeError: aircraftObj is not a constructor
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (controller.js:1327)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (controller.js:1326)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
 (anonymous) @ controller.js:1327
 each @ jquery.min.js:2
 (anonymous) @ controller.js:1326
 dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
 q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
 controller.js:1736
```

Comment: You didn't post the error

Comment: Just send a reproducible error. Here we got nothing to play with, and not even the error stacktrace as @Musa stated...

Comment: It's 3000 lines of javascript,not sure how I'd post just a piece of it.

Comment: `currentPosition = L.latLng[0,0]` and `previousPosition` probably don't do what you want them to, but they don't look likely to throw errors.

Comment: You say, "The second time I call it I get the following error:", but don't display anything about the error.

Comment: Please read **[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** if you don't know how to make those 3000 lines into something others can quickly grasp.

Comment: Sounds like your `aircraftObj` constructor function is overwriting the `aircraftObj` variable.

Comment: Thank you Bergi....you gave me the hint to go dig deeper. I was indeed overwriting the constructor with a varialble that had the same name later on in the code. All working now.